# python -m pip install neo4j throws a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to connect Noe4j to Jupyter notebook
I understood I need to download it to the Jupyter

This is the command I am running:

```
python -m pip install neo4j
```

And this is the output I receive:

```
  File "<ipython-input-19-6129f5c5404d>", line 1
    python -m pip install neo4j
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Ah, you need to run this command from the command line, not inside a `.py` file.

Comment: gut it thank you!

Comment: can write the  command in the command line with the command:                                             !pip install neo4j